# Update Visibility of panels in C# WindowForms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Form looks like this:

[image: Form looks like this.]

I want to show/hide a panel using combo box. But unfortunately, it's not happening as expected. Please check the code.

```
namespace Physics
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    //ComboBox Items are:
    //Distance
    //Time
    //Velocity
    void ControlCreate(object item) 
    {
          switch (item.ToString())
          {
              case "Distance":
                  panel1.Visible = true;   
              break;

              case "Time":
              panel1.Visible = false;
              break;

              case "Velocity":
              panel1.Visible = true;
              break;

              default:
              MessageBox.Show("Default");
              break;
           }
    }
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 f = new Form1();
        f.ControlCreate(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
    }

}
}
```

I know there would be a silly mistake.

Comment: what you are expected? and what is happening?

Comment: I cannot hide/show panel on Indexchanged event.

Comment: Why do you create new control inside the selected index changed? You should change the visibility of the Panel in the *current* Form.

Comment: That's a method name , don't go on name, it's simple, i just want to hide a panel which contain 4 labels and 2 textboxes using a method on indexchanged event

Comment: Please do not beg for urgency or fast answers here - your questions are just the same priority as everyone else's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your `ComboBox` change its `SelectedIndex`, it will go to this event handler:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 f = new Form1();
    f.ControlCreate(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
}
```

Thus, you should handle to hide/show your Panel there.

*Don't* create new form:

```
Form1 f = new Form1(); //unnecessary
```

But simply use the info in your *current* form and change its panel visibility accordingly:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
     switch (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())
      {
          case "Distance":
              panel1.Visible = true;   
          break;

          case "Time":
          panel1.Visible = false;
          break;

          case "Velocity":
          panel1.Visible = true;
          break;

          default:
          MessageBox.Show("Default");
          break;
       }
 }
```

You will get this work, but you may also want to check if your logic to show/hide the entire panel when the selected index of the comboBox is changed itself is OK.

Comment: Thanks, I was creating an unnecessary object.